# GitLab CI/CD with Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, firebase-admin

Would like to automatically deploy Firebase Functions with Git Lab runners.
Having issues with the Firebase Admin SKD private key file

Local environment contains the admin.json file
For reason this file will kept off GitLab (admin.json)
I have created a GitLab runner environment variable containing the admin.json object.

admin.json == gitlab environment variable called admin_token

I've tried using the

`cat >> admin.json << 'END' 
  $admin_token
  END`

To create a temporary admin.json file 
//admin_token is the  environment var on GitLab

```
mage: node:10.11.0 # can be upgraded, depending on your node version used

stages:
    - build
    - deploy

cache:
  paths:
    - project/node_modules/
    - /x/functions/node_modules/

build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo "Build"
        - cd project
        - npm i
        - CI=false npm run build

    artifacts:
        paths:
            - ./project/build
            - ./project/firebase.json
            - ./project/.firebaserc
            - ./project/functions
    only:
        - Production

deploy:
    stage: deploy
    environment: production
    script:
        - echo "Deploy"
        - cd ref_project
        - cd functions
        - cat >> admin.json << 'END'
        - $admin_token
        - END
        - cat admin.json
        - npm i
        - npm -g config set user root
        - npm i -g  firebase-tools
        - firebase use project-xxxxx --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
        - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN  
    only:
        - Production
```

Comment: I recommend you reading the Gitlab's secret variables section here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#secret-variables

Comment: If I'm right, you want to run env variables on Gitlab while deploying your app, but not keep them on it? In that link I shared with you mentioned that, but you'll expose your variables though.